# CSS - Easy way for Containing Floats

Tags: html, css

I read many articles about problems of Containing Floats on websites.

There is also many guides (like [this](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59)) that explain how to fix some issues about this.
What I would like to know is : what about this easy code?

```
.maindiv{width:980px; margin:0 auto;}
```

I tried on many browsers, and looks that it ALWAYS works. So whats the problem with this? I also try with (for example) :

```
.maindiv{width:980px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#000099;}
```

and seems that, although main container got a background-color, the within div (floated) doesnt get any problems.

Im just curios :)

Comment: not sure if the example you referenced and your example do the same thing, the author in the first example deals with floating elements and how they interact with other content on the page, you just contain the float so it does not 'go off' the `.maindiv` horizontally.

Comment: If you have only floats in `.maindiv`, the background on `.maindiv` will not extend around the floated elements in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.maindiv{width:980px; margin:0 auto;}` accomplishes something rather different. An element with an explicit width declaration and a `auto` left and right margin causes that div to be centered.

It most definitely does NOT solve the containing floats issue.

See http://jsfiddle.net/aPmu5/

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with this isolated piece of code, but it will give you problems if you try to give it a background and then insert some floating children.

Comment: Uhm. In fact all my children are float. And if i put `.maindiv{width:980px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#000099;}` i don't get any problems. that's why my question :)

Comment: @markzzz: Please try to assemble a complete example of your code for us to look at. It's likely that you're misattributing the float containment to your CSS declaration on `.maindiv` (e.g., if you have actually included a clear). You might also be misidentifying another sort of containment as float containment (e.g., if your contained elements aren't being floated properly).

Comment: No worries. I understand the real differences between that guide posted as link and my pieces of code. In fact, for each float children i put my own background (that's why i don't inherited the background attribute from parent). I think is the easy way to do these kinds of stuff, isnt it?